# Hibernate validation - autowired returns null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

After looking around, I couldn't find any good solution to this.

My autowired didn't work as expected where it returns null. I've autowired this particular class in other classes and it works so it only doesn't work in constraintvalidator classes.

UserService class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRep;
    
    public void addUser(User user) {
        userRep.save(user);
    }
    
    
    public void deleteUser(long userId) {
        userRep.deleteById(userId);
    }
    
    public List<User> retrieveAllUsers(){
        Iterable<User>temp =userRep.findAll();
        List<User>allUsers = null;
        temp.forEach(allUsers::add);
        return allUsers;
    }
    
    public boolean searchByEmail(String email) {
        return userRep.findByEmail(email);
    }
    
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userRep.save(user);
    }
}
```

Annotation interface class

```
 @Target(ElementType.FIELD) 
    //When will the annotation be processed compilation, runtime etc
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    //Where is the logic
    @Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidator.class)
    @Documented
    public @interface ValidEmail {
        
        //Error message
        String message() default "Invalid email";
        //Required for annotation
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
        
    }
```

Annotation logic class. The autowired here returns null

```
public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;
    //Actual place to place the logic to check if the data is valid or not
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (email == null) {
        return false;
        }
        
        List<User> users = service.retrieveAllUsers();
        if (users.size() > 0) { 
        return Pattern.matches("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", email)
                && service.searchByEmail(email);
        }
        
        else {
            return Pattern.matches("(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", email);
        }
        }
        
    
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidEmail validEmail) {
        validEmail.message();
    }

}
```

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.Alex.Mains", "com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights", "com.Alex.Security"
})
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
public class JpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public Validator validator(final AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
//
//      ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
//              .configure()
//              .constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(beanFactory))
//              .buildValidatorFactory();
//
//      return validatorFactory.getValidator();
//  }
    
}
```

[image]

Edit: Tried @Componenet

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My Suggestion**

Instead of a custom validator, use the existing @EMail and a unique constraint:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  // ...your properties

  @Email
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email.

  // Rest of class...
}
```

**OLD:**

So, first off:

```
List<User> users = service.retrieveAllUsers();
    if (users.size() > 0) {
```

You are fetching all the Users from the database, just to check whether any users exists? This is very, very inefficient. If you are already using Spring Data, you can just do

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM Users")
boolean anyExists();
```

Furthermore, your Service does not get injected, because `EmailValidator` is a POJO (plain old java object) and not a Spring managed component. If you annotate it with `@Component` or `@Service` Spring will take care of injection.

But I would not recommend that. I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but validators are often used on Entities and as such, they get called when the entity is created or updated. You don't want to issue additional queries in those cases.

Like I said, I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you could use the existing `@Email` validator (you can even provide a custom regular expression with the [regexp attribute](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Email.html#regexp--)).

Comment: I tried @Compoenent, it didn't work out. I'm trying to validate if the new email input already exist in the database and whether if follows the email regex

Comment: Possibly because the Validator is in a package that is not included in `@ComponentScan`. If you place your Applicaton class in a package "above" everything else, you don't even need that (i.e. in 'com.Alex').
But again, I don't think you want Validators to be managed components and I don't think you want to issue a query here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tried to include the package in componentscan and it didn't work out. I'm doing a custom annotation that validates the field email.

Comment: Yes I got that... But where is this annotation used? You are checking that a User with given E-Mail exists. This tells me, that you actually want some kind of relationship, e.g., an order placed by an existing user.

Comment: At the user class type level. Yeah say new user enters email, the new email shouldn't already exist in the other existing user's object. Is it cool if I upload the project on github for you take a look?

Comment: Well that's just a unique constraint! That gets enforced at Database level, which is much stronger and better than querying inside your application and hoping that another transaction won't add it or through other means.
Just add `@Column(unique = true)` on your E-Mail property.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with adding the following to application.properties. No idea why but it works

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

Comment: What works? Injection or actual validation? Because that should turn off validation.

Comment: The problem runs without nullexception now. However, running the annotation gets me nullexception in .retrieveAllUsers. I'm trying to figure that out

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with the annotation, your code simply has a bug: `allUsers = null; allUsers::add` You set allUsers to null. You should create a new ArrayList. Although I don't think you necessarily need to convert the result. I four repo extends org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository, that has a findAll method returning List. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--